# Django openid (google-app-engine) error: No module named django_openid_auth

Tags: django, google-app-engine, openid

I'd like my users to be able to log in to my django project using their google accounts login (instead of having to sign up and create a new one). I found this : http://learnedstuffs.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/django-google-account-authentication/

But it doesn't work for me. After deploying my project in to Google apps engine it shows an error: ImportError: No module named django_openid_auth. I've checked many times - i did install django-openid-auth (by virtualenv). I'm new to django and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Can anybody please help me with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: Packages installed in system or virtualenv environments won't get uploaded to GAE production servers. Packages should be in GAE project folder.

Comment: I've been looking for this solution for more than 2 days. Thank you so much!